# regexp: FirstName LastName (domain.com)

Tags: regex

I'd like to create a regular expression, but unfortunately my idea didn't work
The regular expression should only permit the entry of a string consisting of two parts:
Part one: letters (a-z, a-Z), digits (0-9) characters: dot, dash
Part two: should start and end with brackets, and between them allow only: lowercase letters (a-z) and dot

Valid examples:

1. John Smith (contoso.com) -> in this case, part of the first is "John Smith", and the second part is "(contoso.com)"
2. Jerry A. Doe (mail.com) -> in this case, part of the first is "John A. Doe", and the second part is "(mail.com)"
3. Info (mydomain.com) -> in this case, part of the first is "Info", and the second part is "(mydomain.com)"
4. Mary-Jane (mydomain.com) -> in this case, part of the first is
   "Mary-Jane", and the second part is "(mydomain.com)"

No matching examples:

- John Smith
- John Smith contoso.com
- John Smith (Contoso.com)
- Mary_Jane (mydomain.com)

My idea:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.][\(][a-zA-Z0-9\.][\)]
```

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add repetition after your character classes:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\s.\-]+\([a-z.]+\)
```

I also made a few other minor changes, there is no need to put `\(` and `\)` in a character class, and no need to escape `.` inside of a character class.  You also said you want the first group to allow dashes so I added that to the character class.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the dash in the first one.  You said ONLY lowercase letters and dot in the second one, so remove the uppercase and the numbers from the second one.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\s.-]+\([a-z.]+\)
```

And finally, like F.J. said, you need to add repition.  **+** means "1 or more times".

Please remember to select one of the answers as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
^([A-Za-z.\s-]+) (\([a-z.]+\))$
```

***DEMO***

http://regex101.com/r/gR5kN1

***EXPLANATION:***

```
^ assert position at start of a line
1st Capturing group ([A-Za-z.\s-]+)
[A-Za-z.\s-]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
. the literal character .
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
- the literal character -
  matches the character   literally
2nd Capturing group (\([a-z.]+\))
\( matches the character ( literally
[a-z.]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
. the literal character .
\) matches the character ) literally
$ assert position at end of a line
```